# Redirecionar página depois de um formulário de email

Tags: php, html, formulário

Estou fazendo um formulário que precisa chegar no meu email mas quando alguém clicar em submit ele seja redirecionado para uma página de agradecimento.
Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie a página **redirecionamento.php** - que será a página que verificará os dados do formulário e irá redirecionar o usuário para a pagina de agradecimento - e escreva o seguinte código:

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST['submicao']))
    {   
       <!-- faça a validação dos dados submetidos !-->

       header('Location: http://seusite/agradecimento.php');       
    }
?>
```

Em sua página do formulário, faça um include da página de redirecionamento logo após a submissão do formulário

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Código do header !-->
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <!-- Seus labels, etc. do formulario !-->

        <!-- Página de redirecionamento -->
        <?php include "include/redirecionamento.php"; ?>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ou você também pode usar o seguinte código javascript dentro da tag `<form>`

```
<form onsubmit="window.location.href='redirecionamento.php';">
```

Nesse caso, você não precisaria dar o "include".

```
<body>

    <form onsubmit="window.location.href='redirecionamento.php';">>
        <!-- Seus labels, etc. do formulario !-->
    </form >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mas coloco isso no meio do <head>?

Comment: @Luvinicius editei a resposta para ficar mais claro

Comment: Obrigado, mas em javascript fica na mesma posição?

Comment: Mudei a resposta de novo :-)

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! :)